# smarty 'OR' operator is not working?

Tags: html, smarty

```
{if $command2 ne "thanks" || $command1 ne "error"}
 some code <!---Ist Code-->
{/if}

{if $command2 eq "thanks" || ($command1 eq "error"}
<meta name="Robots" content="noindex, nofollow"> <!---2nd Code-->
{/if}
```

I am trying this but its not working.its showing both 1st and 2nd code
Give me one solution

Comment: which values for $command1 and $command2 are you testing with?

Comment: based on URL $command1 and $command2 already assigned variable

Comment: but the thing is, for example if $command1 not equals to "error" and $command2 equals to "thanks" both codes will be shown. but for other values things may change. test values are important to solve your problem.

Comment: I want like this  if ($command2 == 'thank') or ($command1 == 'error') {<meta name="Robots" content="noindex, nofollow"> <!---2nd Code want to display this-->}

Comment: i tried with giving command1 as "error" and command2 as "thanks" but it showing both

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your problem is with logic. Try && operator with `ne` case like;

```
{if $command2 ne "thanks" && $command1 ne "error"}
 some code <!---Ist Code-->
{/if}

{if $command2 eq "thanks" || ($command1 eq "error"}
<meta name="Robots" content="noindex, nofollow"> <!---2nd Code-->
{/if}
```

it's a basic programming knowledge. when you invert the case, invert `OR`s to `AND`s, too.

Keep in mind that depending on your needs, it might be vice versa like;

```
{if $command2 ne "thanks" || $command1 ne "error"}
 some code <!---Ist Code-->
{/if}

{if $command2 eq "thanks" && ($command1 eq "error"}
<meta name="Robots" content="noindex, nofollow"> <!---2nd Code-->
{/if}
```

Both makes sense in different scenerios.

Update: After your second comment, it's clear that you need the first example at the top.

Answer (score 0):

please add ( ) brackets around your condition like

```
{if ($comment1 eq "thanks") || ($comment2 eq "error")}
do something
{/if}
```